# Logarithmic functional equation $f(xy)=f(x)+(y)$ with the additional condition $f(x)-f(x_0)\le a(x-x_0)$

Tags: logarithms, functional-equations

Having trouble attacking below problem. Any help is very much appreciated:

Let $f: (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function which satisfies the logarithmic functional equation
$$f(xy)=f(x)+(y).$$
Show that if there exists $x_0>0$ and $a>0$ such that $f$ satisfies
$$f(x)-f(x_0)\le a(x-x_0) \quad \text{for } x>0,$$
then there exists a constant $c>0$ such that $f(x)=c \log x$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Could you please describe what is meant by the logarithm functional equation?

Comment: Added it to the post.

Comment: As stated, this is false, because it is not true for $f \equiv 0$. However that can fixed by changing it to "$c \ge 0$". If you allow $a < 0$ as well, it would be true if no restrictions are placed on $c$. What you need the condition (with $a > 0$) for is to show that $f$ must be continuous, and $f(x) < f(x_0)$ when $x < x_0$. From continuity and the functional equation alone, you can prove it is some multiple of the logarithm function by starting with an induction argument, then expanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the neatest way to think about it is by defining $ g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ with $ g ( x ) = f ( \exp x ) $ for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. Doing so, we can get
$$ g ( x + y ) = g ( x ) + g ( y ) \tag 0 \label 0 $$
for all $ x , y \in \mathbb R $ from the original functional equation for $ f $. \eqref{0} is known as [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation), and functions like $ g $ satisfying it are called [additive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map). This functional equation is well-studied, and you can find all sorts of things about it here and there. The post "[Overview of basic facts about Cauchy functional equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/423492/229831)" contains some of the most famous properties of additive functions. One that is relevant here is that \eqref{0} has solutions that are not linear over $ \mathbb R $. Another relevant fact is that the graph of any nonlinear additive function is dense in $ \mathbb R ^ 2 $. This means that if there is a disk in the real plane containing no point on the graph of an additive function $ g $, then $ g $ must be of the form $ g ( x ) = c x $ for some constant $ c \in \mathbb R $. Here is where the condition
$$ f ( x ) - f ( x _ 0 ) \le a ( x - x _ 0 ) \tag 1 \label 1 $$
comes into play. We can substitute $ \exp x $ for $ x $ in \eqref{1} and get
$$ g ( x ) \le f ( x _ 0 ) + a ( \exp x - x _ 0 ) \tag 2 \label 2 $$
for all $ x \in \mathbb R $. While \eqref{2} might not look very pretty, we only need to note that it implies that the graph of $ g $ does not cross any *high-enough* disks. More explicitly, consider the disk $ D $ in $ \mathbb R ^ 2 $ with unit radius centered at the point $ ( x _ 0 , y _ 0 ) $, where $ y _ 0 = f ( x _ 0 ) + a \bigl ( \exp ( x _ 0 + 1 ) - x _ 0 \bigr ) + 1 $. Then, for every $ x \in ( x _ 0 - 1 , x _ 0 + 1 ) $ we have
$$ g ( x ) \le f ( x _ 0 ) + a ( \exp x - x _ 0 ) < f ( x _ 0 ) + a \bigl ( \exp ( x _ 0 + 1 ) - x _ 0 \bigr ) = y _ 0 - 1 \text , $$
which implies that the point $ \bigl ( x , g ( x ) \bigr ) $ lies outside $ D $. We then get linearity of $ g $, which translates to
$$ f ( x ) = c \log x $$
for some constant $ c \in \mathbb R $ and all $ x \in ( 0 , + \infty ) $.

To prove $ c > 0 $, note that setting $ x = \frac { x _ 0 } e $ in \eqref{1} we get
$$ c ( \log x _ 0 - 1 ) - c \log x _ 0 \le a \left ( \frac { x _ 0 } e - x _ 0 \right ) < 0 $$
and therefore
$$ c \ge a \left ( 1 - \frac 1 e \right ) x _ 0 > 0 \text . $$